# Deleting questions that promote understanding?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I just recognized and wondered that [a question was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59114927/5527985) ([Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uAT3MVi9f5AJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114927/the-origin-of-lookahead-and-lookbehind)) by some users that was less about code, but more about understanding.

When I first read this question I was also confused and thought that was weird - but after thinking of it I understood the opening poster very well and tried to help.

I really can't see, why such question is deleted and find that very annoying.

Comment: I can somewhat understand the closure (I'd leave the question open though), but I don't get why the question was deleted. The question should actually be *Why is lookahead called 'lookahead'?* leaving away all the *ridicolous* overhead.

Comment: This question reads not like a question about regex, but what "ahead" and "behind" means and that looks like a language barrier issue, not a programming related question.

Comment: @Tom The question asks what "ahead" and "behind" means in context with regex lookarounds. Or better, why they are termed alike. There was no language barrier, but an understanding problem about regex lookarounds. If regex is programming related, the question is related as well.

Comment: Thank you all for undeleting the question. Not caring too much if it is closed or not. But the new closing reason "opintion based" is also not correct imho. However, wishing relaxed christmas days, fatly meals and many presents! Please let me know, if I should remove this question here at meta, because it's solved.

Comment: The question in now re-opened, but still deleted. It needs one more vote to get undeleted too.

Comment: Thank you for reopening the question once again (sadly it was deleted again by some users in meanwhile since its first undeletion from community yesterday).

Comment: Perhaps because [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)?

Comment: Why delete this meta question? There may be similar questions in the future, and this one can be referred to (for example, as precedent).